# How to create a web application with host header?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-application, host-header

I'm trying to create a **web application with host header** in SharePoint 2013 but when I populate the host header field, site collections under that web application are not displayed (404 Error). I followed the steps specified in the below links,

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Steps-To-Create-Host-0ab7bcc3

http://www.mssharepointtips.com/tip.asp?id=929&page=1

But none worked. How can I create a web application with host header?

Comment: Do you have a dns entry for your host header? Have you tried adding the hostheader to the local "hosts" file showing to the ip of your sharepoint?

Comment: @Andreas yeah i have dns entry for the host header.  I also tried adding the host header to the hosts file as mentioned in this [link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/82956c/create-a-web-application-with-host-header-in-sharepoint-2010/). But still same error

Comment: What are you using as hostheader entry? Have you looked into the SharePoint Logs if there is something useful? Have you added your hostheader entry as trusted site in IE? Sorry, that I got more questions than answers, but it works for me just like in the links.

Comment: It's okay :) I checked the SharePoint logs but no useful info in it and also not added the entry as trusted site in IE ( this trusted site adding is not mandatory right?)

Comment: In my opinion it's mandatory, couldn't find a msdn site stating this right away, but we always tell customers to do so, because else things might not work